# Map Directions From Pins

Tags: class, mapkit, mapkitannotation, mkmapitem, mkplacemark

Im creating a tagging app where users can tag Street Art to a map. I want users to be able to click on the pins (i) callout button and be taken to Apple Maps.

This function should allow that to happen however I get an error "instance member 'coordinate' can not be used on type 'art'"  -

func  openInMaps() {

```
    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000

    let coordinates = art.coordinate

    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates!, regionDistance, regionDistance)

    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]

    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates!, addressDictionary: nil)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)

    mapItem.name = art.name

    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)



    }
```

And this is my art class -

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import CoreLocation

class art {

let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var name: String!
var location: String!
var type: String!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?


init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

    ref = snapshot.ref

    name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String

    location = snapshotValue["location"] as! String

    coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: snapshotValue["lat"] as! Double, longitude: snapshotValue["lng"] as! Double)

   // type = snapshotValue["type"] as! String

}
}
```

Would be great for someone to point me in the right direction or tell me if what Im doing is wrong! thanks.